# give suggestion data display base on the Locale Click to flag this post

Tags: java, struts2

```
<s:iterator value="listObject">
<s:component template="abc.vm">
        <s:param name="text" value="listValue" />
        <s:param name="prefix" value="listIndex" />
</s:component>
</s:iterator>
```

`listObject` is a `LinkedList` object. `listValue` and `listIndex` is of `Object` type. 
i have two properties file:

messages.properties:

```
activity.name=activity
```

messages_fr.properties:

```
activity.name=activity_fr
```

i want to add `Localization` feature so that `LinkedList` populate and display all the activities based on the `Locale`.

please suggest in this regard.

Comment: In the future, please use the `edit` link below the question to improve the question instead of reposting one more. You've now two dead questions around ( [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941274/scomponent-in-struts2) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940996/simplify-the-struts-tag)). I recommend to click the `delete` link on both.

Comment: thanks BalusC. but i am not finding delete link

Comment: Oh, right, you're unregistered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial on [internationalization](http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/23/howto-struts-2-i18n/) in struts2.